# find way to disallow number

Tags: html, regex

I need a Regex pattern to restricted number in the Name Field input, I don't receive the name as like

12345678, 3241238215, 4323438,. Mean I don't need like this just mix text number.

not all put numbers without text.

```
<!-- Name -->
            <div>
                <x-label for="name" :value="__('Name')" />

                <x-input id="name" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="name" pattern="<HERE!>" :value="old('name')" required autofocus />
            </div>
```

I

Comment: `.*\p{Alpha}.*` ?

Comment: Do you want allow a) just numbers b) no numbers at all c) no numbers at the beginning d) something else?

Answer (score 0):

`".*[A-Za-z].*"`

`"."` match any character
`"*"` match zero or more of the previous character
`".*"` match any string
`[]` match any one of the characters listed inside
`A-Z` match any thing between upper-case A and upper-case Z (all upper-case)
`a-z` match any thing between upper-case a and upper-case z (all lower-case)
`[A-Za-z]` match any alpha character
`".*[A-Za-z].*"` match an alpha char in any string

you could also use this cheatsheet: https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/